# C2DM Device to Cloud data transfer possible?

Tags: android

Is it possible to send data from device to cloud in c2dm? If yes how can this be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think so. C2DM is a server to mobile notification system. If you have to do it the other way round you can expose a service on the cloud and access it directly from the device. What would be the point of using C2DM anyway?